# Using exception with raise_application_error

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql

I'm developing with Oracle 11g. How can I use a named exception in `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` like this:

```
DECLARE
  my_fault EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (my_fault, -20000);
BEGIN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(my_fault, 'my error message');
END;
```

But I got an error. I have to use the error code explicity.
The Oracle Database Documentation says:

> Restriction on exception
>
> You can use exception only in an EXCEPTION_INIT pragma, RAISE statement, RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR invocation, or exception handler.

I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to raise exceptions in Oracle.  If you want to specify your own message, you wouldn't declare a local variable of type `exception`.  You'd simply put the error code in your `raise_application_error` call

```
BEGIN
  raise_applicaton_error( -20001, 'Some message' );
END;
```

If you want to declare a local exception type, then you wouldn't use `raise_application_error` to throw it.  You'd just use `raise`.  But then you won't be able to specify a custom message.

```
DECLARE
  my_fault EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (my_fault, -20000);
BEGIN
  RAISE my_fault;
END;
```

If you just don't like hard-coding the error code in your `raise_application_error` call, you can put that in a local `integer` variable

```
declare
  myfault_code integer := -20001;
begin
  raise_application_error( myfault_code, 'Some error' );
end;
```

Comment: That just what I knew before. But why is only `RAISE my_fault;` valid? Why not together with `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`?

Comment: @DavidZurborg - I'm not sure I understand the question.  You can use `raise_application_error` but not with a local exception type.  You can use `raise` with a local exception type but not with a custom error message.  If you are asking why `raise_application_error` doesn't use local exception types, I'm not sure what you are looking for other than "because that's the way Oracle is designed".